# Installing MySQL (MariaDB) on Centos7

Tags: installation, centos7, mariadb

New to Centos7, trying to install MariaDB with:

```
sudo yum install mariadb-server mariadb
```

And this is what it spits out:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package mariadb-server is obsoleted by MariaDB-server, trying to install MariaDB-server-10.1.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64 instead
Package mariadb is obsoleted by MariaDB-client, trying to install MariaDB-client-10.1.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.5-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Data::Dumper) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.5-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.6.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.627-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlServer) >= 0.2001 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(RPC::PlClient) >= 0.2000 for package: perl-DBI-1.627-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package perl-Data-Dumper.x86_64 0:2.145-3.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-PlRPC.noarch 0:0.2020-14.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon) >= 0.13 for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Test) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Net::Daemon::Log) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Zlib) for package: perl-PlRPC-0.2020-14.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-IO-Compress.noarch 0:2.061-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Zlib) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Compress::Raw::Bzip2) >= 2.061 for package: perl-IO-Compress-2.061-2.el7.noarch
---> Package perl-Net-Daemon.noarch 0:0.48-5.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2.x86_64 0:2.061-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib.x86_64 1:2.061-4.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================
 Package           Arch   Version              Repository       Size
=====================================================================
Installing:
 MariaDB-client    x86_64 10.1.5-1.el7.centos  centos7-x86_64-mariadb-10-1
                                                                37 M
 MariaDB-server    x86_64 10.1.5-1.el7.centos  centos7-x86_64-mariadb-10-1
                                                                92 M
Installing for dependencies:
 jemalloc          x86_64 3.6.0-1.el7          centos7-x86_64-mariadb-10-1
                                                               104 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2
                   x86_64 2.061-3.el7          centos7-x86_64   32 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib
                   x86_64 1:2.061-4.el7        centos7-x86_64   57 k
 perl-DBI          x86_64 1.627-4.el7          centos7-x86_64  802 k
 perl-Data-Dumper  x86_64 2.145-3.el7          centos7-x86_64   47 k
 perl-IO-Compress  noarch 2.061-2.el7          centos7-x86_64  260 k
 perl-Net-Daemon   noarch 0.48-5.el7           centos7-x86_64   51 k
 perl-PlRPC        noarch 0.2020-14.el7        centos7-x86_64   36 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+8 Dependent packages)

Total size: 131 M
Installed size: 557 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/centos7-x86_64-mariadb-10-1/packages/jemalloc-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1bb943db: NOKEY


Public key for jemalloc-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

What's the deal with `jemalloc-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` not being installed? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You installed a third party repository for (a beta version of) MariaDB, but you did not install the GPG public key for that repository. Go back to wherever you got it, and follow their directions for obtaining and installing the public key.